# Which part of code goes into smart contract and which not?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, tokens, contract-design

I'm about to venture into a more complex web3 project but I'm confused on when should the code be inside a smart contract and when not?

Since virtually all dapps have web2 elements - frontend, UI and even backend, but which part of backend should be in web3?

As far as I can know things that go into web3 are,

1. Token minting
2. Token governing
3. Token transacting

But what else?